# Elixir Phoenix How to change and retain class using %JS{} in this modal text editor example

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The code below lets a user click on a list item (called a testbed.note) and as a result a modal pops up whereby they can either preview or edit the content.

The problem is if the user keeps the editor open and the modal closes, the next time the modal is opened it does so in the "edit" state.

In the code, the user should NEVER be able to open the modal and have it default to the edit state. In other words, each time the modal launches it should always be in preview mode.

I tried placing %JS{} code to toggle the class when the user clicks the submit button. It didn't work.

I have linked a video:  https://imgur.com/q8Junfb

```
defmodule AppWeb.PageLive do 

  use AppWeb, :live_view  
  alias App.Testbeds 
  def mount(_params, _session, socket)do   
     {:ok, assign(socket, testbeds: Testbeds.list_testbeds())}   
  end

    def button_event("invoke_editing") do
    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing_button")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview_button")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing")
  end

  def button_event("invoke_preview") do
    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview_button")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing_button")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview")

  end

  def handle_event("send", params, socket) do

    {:noreply, socket}
  end





  def render(assigns) do  
     ~H"""



    <%= for testbed <- @testbeds do %>
        <.modal id={"notes-modal-#{testbed.id}"}>
            <.button phx-click={button_event("invoke_editing")} id="editing_button" class="hidden">
              Preview
            </.button>
            <.button phx-click={button_event("invoke_preview")} id="preview_button">
              Edit Me
            </.button>
            <div id="editing"> PREVIEWING THE WORK</div>
            <form phx-submit = "send"   id="preview" class="hidden">
              <textarea value = {testbed.note}></textarea>
              <.button type="submit" phx-click={hide_modal("notes-modal-#{testbed.id}")}>SAVE WORK</.button>
            </form>
        </.modal>

    <%= if testbed.note do %>
      <div phx-click={show_modal("notes-modal-#{testbed.id}")}>READ ME  ...<%= testbed.note %></div>
    <% end %>
       
    <% end %>
       
      """
  end

end
```

**EDIT**

I do not know how to set selects with dynamic ID's and still select them using JS{}. As it stands, the current ID's repeat

EDIT

I tried to change the code so that it only consist of unique ID's. There are no errors rendered and the code looks like it should work but the "item" argument is not being read in the function bodie(s). `IO.inspect item` does not log anything when the button(s) are clicked.

```
defmodule AppWeb.PageLive do 

  use AppWeb, :live_view  
  alias App.Testbeds 
  def mount(_params, _session, socket)do   
     {:ok, assign(socket, testbeds: Testbeds.list_testbeds())}   
  end

    def button_event("invoke_editing",item) do
      IO.inspect item
    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing_button-#{item}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button-#{item}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button-#{item}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview_button-#{item}")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview-#{item}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview-#{item}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing-#{item}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing-#{item}")
  end

  def button_event("invoke_preview", item) do
    IO.inspect item
    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview_button-#{item}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button-#{item}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button-#{item}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing_button-#{item}")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing-#{item}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing-#{item}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview-#{item}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview-#{item}")

  end

  def handle_event("send", params, socket) do
    IO.inspect "TEST"

     
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  

  def render(assigns) do  
     ~H"""


    <%= for testbed <- @testbeds do %>
        <.modal id={"notes-modal-#{testbed.id}"}>
            <.button phx-click={button_event("invoke_editing",testbed.id)} id={"editing-button-#{testbed.id}"} class="hidden">
              Preview
            </.button>
            <.button phx-click={button_event("invoke_preview",testbed.id)} id={"preview-button-#{testbed.id}"} >
              Edit Me
            </.button>
            <div id={"editing-#{testbed.id}"}> PREVIEWING THE WORK</div>
            <form phx-submit = "send"   id={"preview-#{testbed.id}"} class="hidden">
              <textarea value = {testbed.note}></textarea>
              <.button type="submit" >SAVE WORK</.button>
            </form>
        </.modal>

      <%= if testbed.note do %>
        <div phx-click={show_modal("notes-modal-#{testbed.id}")}>READ ME  ...<%= testbed.note %></div>
      <% end %>
       
    <% end %>
       
      """
  end

end
```

**EDIT**
Removed all the duplicate ID's again and it works the same as in the video.

```
defmodule AppWeb.PageLive do 

  use AppWeb, :live_view  
  alias App.Testbeds 
  def mount(_params, _session, socket)do   
     {:ok, assign(socket, testbeds: Testbeds.list_testbeds())}   
  end

    def button_event("invoke_editing", eleID) do
      IO.inspect eleID
    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
  end

  def button_event("invoke_preview",eleID) do
    IO.inspect eleID
    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")

  end

  def handle_event("send", params, socket) do
    IO.inspect "TEST"
    IO.inspect params

     
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  

  def render(assigns) do  
     ~H"""

    <%= for testbed <- @testbeds do %>
        <.modal id={"notes-modal-#{testbed.id}"}>
            <.button phx-click={button_event("invoke_editing",testbed.id)} id={"editing_button_#{testbed.id}"} class="hidden">
              Preview
            </.button>
            <.button phx-click={button_event("invoke_preview",testbed.id)} id={"preview_button_#{testbed.id}"}>
              Edit Me
            </.button>
            <div id={"editing_#{testbed.id}"}> PREVIEWING THE WORK</div>
            <form phx-submit = "send"   id={"preview_#{testbed.id}"} class="hidden">
              <textarea value = {testbed.note}></textarea>
              <.button type="submit" >SAVE WORK</.button>
            </form>
        </.modal>

    <%= if testbed.note do %>
      <div phx-click={show_modal("notes-modal-#{testbed.id}")}>READ ME  ...<%= testbed.note %></div>
    <% end %>
       
    <% end %>
       
      """
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
defmodule AppWeb.PageLive do 

  use AppWeb, :live_view  
  alias App.Testbeds 
  def mount(_params, _session, socket)do   
     {:ok, assign(socket, testbeds: Testbeds.list_testbeds())}   
  end

    def button_event("invoke_editing", eleID) do
      IO.inspect eleID
    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
  end

  def button_event("invoke_preview",eleID) do
    IO.inspect eleID
    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")

  end

  def handle_event("send", params, socket) do
    eleID = params["id_data"]

    %JS{}
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#preview_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#editing_button_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("active", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.remove_class("hidden", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")
    |> JS.add_class("active", to: "#preview_#{eleID}")
    {:noreply, redirect(socket, to: "/")}
  end

  

  def render(assigns) do  
     ~H"""
    <%= for testbed <- @testbeds do %>
        <.modal id={"notes-modal-#{testbed.id}"}>
            <.button phx-click={button_event("invoke_editing",testbed.id)} id={"editing_button_#{testbed.id}"} class="hidden">
              Preview
            </.button>
            <.button phx-click={button_event("invoke_preview",testbed.id)} id={"preview_button_#{testbed.id}"}>
              Edit Me
            </.button>
            <div id={"editing_#{testbed.id}"}> PREVIEWING THE WORK</div>
            <form phx-submit = "send"   id={"preview_#{testbed.id}"} class="hidden">
          <input value = {testbed.id} name="id_data" hidden/>
              <textarea value = {testbed.note} name="data"> </textarea>
              <.button type="submit" >SAVE WORK</.button>
            </form>
        </.modal>
    <%= if testbed.note do %>
      <div phx-click={show_modal("notes-modal-#{testbed.id}")}>READ ME  ...<%= testbed.note %></div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
      """
  end
end
```

Comment: So what did you even end up changing? Just the `{:noreply, redirect(socket, to: "/"}` ?

Comment: The submit button runs code to zero out the CSS classes.  It still has a problem in that if the user clicks outside of the modal to close it there is no function to reset the CSS but I figure that is better presented as a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave here almost certainly does not work because there are a lot of non-unique element ids on the same page. As soon as there is more than one `testbed` you have more than one `preview_button`, more than one `editing_button` and so on.

Since live_view's JS implementation relies heavily on the ids duplicated IDs cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: I don't know how to assign elements dynamic ID's and still select the elements using  %JS{}

Comment: I suspect you are already doing something similar in your example with `show_modal` and `hide_modal`, which seem to already use the testbed id as part of their HTML id. In the end just add the dynamic part to the selector in the `to` like  so: `JS.add_class("hidden", to: "#editing_button_#{testbed.id}")`

Comment: I fixed the duplicate ID's and it seems to be on the way to being fixed. Thank you